# Using arrow functions with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

Is it possible? I am not sure, since d3 makes heavy use of `this` rebindings and this seems to conflict with ES6 [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

For instance, the following works fine:

```
// Working fine
var data = [1,2,3]
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height', 500).attr('width', 500).style('background-color', 'orange');
var gs = svg.selectAll('g').data(data).enter();
gs.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function () { return Math.random()*500; })
    .attr('cy', function () { return Math.random()*500; })
    .attr('r', function () { return Math.random()*100; })
    .each(function () { console.log(this); });  // this is bound to the current element in the enter selection
```

While the following does not work as expected (`this` is not bound to the current element in the enter selection but to `Window` object):

```
var data = [1,2,3]
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height', 500).attr('width', 500).style('background-color', 'blue');
var gs = svg.selectAll('g').data(data).enter();
gs.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', () => Math.random()*500)
    .attr('cy', () => Math.random()*500)
    .attr('r', () => Math.random()*100)
    .each(() => console.log(this)); // this is bound to Window object
```

Related fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jarandaf/afrgwyox/).

Comment: @chriskelly your example simply sets the same value for all the elements in the selection, that's not what I want achieve (that's why functions are used in a per-element basis)

Comment: When I run your example the only difference I see is the output console log. But why would you want to access ```this```. This is an interesting question but I would like to know a case where it would be an issue.

Comment: @chriskelly it's a pretty concrete use case (have some function which I want to reuse that creates a complex structure of elements within the svg group, I need `this` to know what group I am referencing to, where new elements will be appended).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use arrow functions if you don't need access to `this` of the current element.

Fallback to the old style functions for cases where you want to access `this` of the current element.

Or use explicit binding to allow your *function* (not arrow function) to access whatever object you want using `.bind()`

To avoid working with `this` you have the option of using d3 name or class selectors to conveniently access any element. e.g.:

```
var stuffINeed = svg.selectAll('.someClass');
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using d3v4, you can access the current DOM node like this:

```
gs.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', () => Math.random()*500)
    .attr('cy', () => Math.random()*500)
    .attr('r', () => Math.random()*100)
    .each((d, i, j) => console.log(j[i])); 
        // j is current group, i is current index
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to modify the behaviour of an arrow function. Their binding is 'hardcoded' and cannot be changed by re-binding with the `bind` method or by invoking any other Function method that accepts an explicit execution context (e.g. `apply`). The same can be said of any bound function -- once bound, the returned function is bound *forever*.

> Is it possible?

With the above in mind, if d3 uses `bind`ing to provide convenient chaining behaviour, this **cannot be achieved** using arrow functions until d3's API is modified in some way to accommodate them.