# D3.js event listeners cannot access "this" when ES6 arrow functions are used

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use D3.js event listeners with arrow functions, but it does not seem to work.

***this*** is bind to **undefined**.

How can I access ***this*** using ES6 arrow functions?

ES5:

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', '10')
  .attr('cx', (d) => x(d.day))
  .attr('cy', (d) => y(d.amount))
  .on('mouseenter', function (d) {
    console.log(this); // output '<circle r="10" cx="10" cy="1"/>'
  });
```

ES6 (using arrow function):

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', '10')
  .attr('cx', (d) => x(d.day))
  .attr('cy', (d) => y(d.amount))
  .on('mouseenter', (d) => {
    console.log(this); // output: 'undefined'
  });
```

Comment: Arrow functions **are not** a replacement for `function`. Nor are they shorthand. They are fundamentally different concepts and are not interchangeable

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32881022/using-arrow-functions-with-d3?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.  (Below is my poor attempt at explaining this behaviour.  You're likely better off [reading this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

The context (`this`) in which an arrow function is executed will be the context in which they are defined (What ever `this` is outside the function)

D3 likely sets the context of your event listener to be the object which is emitting the event (As in your ES5 example).

But, by using arrow functions, you are forcing the context to be bound to the context in which you defined the function.  In your case, this context is undefined / window as your code is not contained within another function.

Perhaps it is better explained if I convert your ES6 example back into ES5):

```
var self = this;    
svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', '10')
      .attr('cx', (d) => x(d.day))
      .attr('cy', (d) => y(d.amount))
      .on('mouseenter', (d) => {
        console.log(self); // output: 'undefined'
      });
```

My advice to fix your issue is simple.  Use a regular `function` as your event subscriber (There is also no benefit of using arrow functions for your two 'attr' subscribers).

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', '10')
  .attr('cx', (d) => x(d.day))
  .attr('cy', (d) => y(d.amount))
  .on('mouseenter', function(d) {
    console.log(this); // output '<circle r="10" cx="10" cy="1"/>'

  });
```