# d3 Cannot read property 'getPropertyValue' of undefined on mouseover

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, d3.js

Trying to use a callback function `.call()` on mouseover to change opacity. Is this is a wrong selection? I've noticed that if I change `const mouseOverFunc = d => d3.selectAll("circle")` or even `const mouseOverFunc = d => circle` this leads all circles to show up. How to display one circle at a time? I understand that the promblem is I dont have to do `groups.selectAll("circle")` instead I have to append circle to groups same as I do with a path, but what I don't understand is to have access **emissions** `d.year` and `d.amount` for `"cx" : xScale` and `"cy" : yScale`.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/edgarkiljak/pen/JeXXdV)

```
    let groups = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("g")



        groups.append("title")
            .text(d => d.country)


       groups
        .append("path").classed("line", true)
        .attr("d", d => line(d.emissions))
        .style("stroke-width", d => 
            d.country === "China" ? 1 : 0.2
        )

       let circle = groups.selectAll("circle")
            .data(d => d.emissions)
            .enter()
            .append("circle");


           circle.attrs({
                "cx": d => xScale(d.year),
                "cy": d => yScale(d.amount),
                "r" : 3
            })
            .style("opacity", 0)




           circle.on("mouseover", () => 
                d3.select(this)
                    .call(mouseOverFunc));

            const mouseOverFunc = selection => 
                selection
                    .transition()
                    .duration(10)
                    .style("opacity", 1)
                    .style("fill", "turquoise")
                    .attr("r", 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like written in altocumulus' comment, the reason is that `this` does work [differently with arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34086193/d3-js-event-listeners-cannot-access-this-when-es6-arrow-functions-are-used). If you are using an arrow function, you cannot use `d3.select(this)`.

You can solve your problem in two ways:

- use a normal `function() { }`
- use [`(d, i, node) => d3.select(nodes[i])`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532635/d3-js-v4-access-current-dom-element-in-es6-arrow-function-event-listener)

Examples:

```
  circle.on("mouseover", function() { 
    d3.select(this)
      .call(mouseOverFunc);
  });
    
  const mouseOverFunc = selection => 
    selection
      .transition()
      .duration(10)
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("fill", "turquoise")
      .attr("r", 3);
```

OR

```
 circle.on("mouseover", (d, i, nodes) => 
   d3.select(nodes[i])
     .call(mouseOverFunc));
   
 const mouseOverFunc = selection => 
   selection
     .transition()
     .duration(10)
     .style("opacity", 1)
     .style("fill", "turquoise")
     .attr("r", 3);
```